# Creating a website with an interactive calendar and time slots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I am quite new to web development with good experience in *HTML, CSS, PHP* and novice experience with *JQuery and JavaScript*. I'm in the process of producing a **website** that acts as an **appointment system** where a:

- user *(patient)* can view available dates and times of a particular doctor for an appointment.
- also the user should see a calendar on the page with available time slots for each day.
- and the website should check with a database in MS Access for available appointments with a doctor.

Could anyone guide me through the process of creating such functionality on my website or direct me to examples where this type of feature has been implemented by someone else? I have seen an example at this [link](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) but I don't know how I would put it in a new, empty website to see it working :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://fullcalendar.io/ check this out.

Comment: thanks @Gagan . I've decided I like the selectable.html one. Where can I  change the time intervals of the calendar? instead of having 30m intervals can I change it to every 20m? And also only having the times between 8:30am and 5pm?

Comment: actually working on that bit now, getting the hang of it :) so grateful for showing me that calendar

Answer (score 0):

Add like this,

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 businessHours: {
  start: '10:00',
  end: '18:00',
  dow: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 },
 defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
 defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
 editable: true,
 events: [{
  title: 'All Day Event',
  start: '2014-06-01'
 }, {
  title: 'Long Event',
  start: '2014-06-07',
  end: '2014-06-10'
 }, {
  id: 999,
  title: 'Repeating Event',
  start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
 }, {
  id: 999,
  title: 'Repeating Event',
  start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
 }, {
  title: 'Meeting',
  start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
  end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
 }, {
  title: 'Lunch',
  start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
 }, {
  title: 'Birthday Party',
  start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
 }, {
  title: 'Click for Google',
  url: 'http://google.com/',
  start: '2014-06-28'
 }]
});
```

Comment: thanks @Gagan. Really getting the hang of this calendar now :) one thing though.. when the user selects a 'slot' I don't want a popup window appearing to type something in.. how would I stop that from happening?

Comment: still having no luck in finding a way of doing it :/